# Windows 8 driver for 945GM

Tags: windows-8, drivers

I am wondering about installing Windows 8 on my five year old laptop (Core 2 Duo, 4 gigs of ram), but I have a concern about graphics drivers. It uses the integrated 945GM chipset, which is one of the chipsets that Intel won't release drivers for:

> Intel has no plans to release Windows 8 graphics drivers for the following older Intel graphics controllers. However, updates for older graphics controllers may be available through Microsoft Windows Update.

What does that mean in practise?  If I were to install Windows 8 on this machine would it be unable to display graphics properly, or just perform badly, or run in a degraded way, whatever that may mean?

Is there a way to check whether Microsoft have their own driver in Windows Update?

I am aware of the Windows 8 Upgrade Assistant, which I assume would be able to check, but at the moment this laptop is only running Ubuntu!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you will face any problems
as I installed Windows 8 PRO on my machine which has Intel Integrated graphics that is way older than yours and it worked pretty well as I installed a driver update from windows update.

So you may not have any problem. You know windows is good with having Intel Drivers :)

Comment: +1  Same for me.  Old Dell laptop with Intel graphics and it worked from the get go.